# Advise how to use "breqn.sty" with "xmltex.tex"

Tags: equations

When we include `\usepackage{breqn}` in

```
\XMLelement{TEI.2}{}
  { \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{ifthen,url}
    \usepackage{breqn}
    \begin{document}  }
  {\end{document}}
```

we are getting the below error:

> ! !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! !
>   Argh, internal LaTeX3 error!
>
> Module kernel, message name "command-already-defined": Arguments '

Kindly advise how to modify the below macro in `"xmltex.tex"`  to avoid the above error:

```
% set up 7bit range
\count@0
\catcode0=13
\gdef\XML@tempa{
 \begingroup
   \uccode0\count@
  \uppercase{\endgroup
    \edef^^@{
      \ifnum\catcode\count@=11 %
        \noexpand\utfeightay\else\noexpand\utfeightax\fi
      \noexpand^^@}
    \expandafter\edef\csname 8:\string^^@\endcsname{\string^^@}}
 \ifnum\count@<127\advance\count@1 \expandafter\XML@tempa\fi}
\XML@tempa
\catcode0=9
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 2):

Really I wouldn't recommend `xmltex` these days, I wrote it but I think that's perhaps the first time I have run it for a decade or so....

Loading `breqn` and so `expl3` after `xmltex` has changed things around could presumably be made to work but really I wouldn't try (or at least I did try just now and it's more work than is reasonable)

You can load `breqn` early, before `xmltex` starts by editing `manual.tex` (for example) so it looks like

```
\def\xmlfile{manual.xml}
\RequirePackage{breqn}
\input xmltex
```

and then use `pdflatex` rather than `pdfxmltex` that then loads all the packages without error but then the docuemnt gets in to an infinite loop processing URL

```
! Interruption.
\Url@String ->h
               ttp://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
l.68 </front>

? 
! Interruption.
\Url@String ->h
               ttp://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
l.68 </front>
```

On balance, I would say don't use `breqn` with `xmltex`. If you want to use `breqn` (or even if you do not) it is these days far easier to use XSLT or some other XML aware processing language to write out your XML as normal tex syntax then you can use whatever latex constructs you need.

Answer (score 2):

One can get past the issue loading `expl3` by changing the nature of `^^@` (ASCII null), something like

```
\begingroup
  \catcode`\^^@=\active
  \gdef\savenull{%
    \let\savednull^^@\let^^@\undefined
  }%
  \gdef\restorenull{\let^^@\savednull}
\endgroup

\XMLelement{TEI.2}{}
  { \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{ifthen,url}
    \savenull
    \usepackage{expl3}
    \restorenull
    \begin{document}  }
  {\end{document}}
```

Probably this can/should be sorted in `expl3` itself (we need to watch for an active null before applying our own definition).

I can get `breqn` to _load`by then dealing with the nature of`?`

```
\XMLelement{TEI.2}{}
  { \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{ifthen,url}
    \setupnull
    \catcode`\?=12 %
    \usepackage{breqn}
    \restorenull
    \catcode`\?=\active
    \begin{document}  }
  {\end{document}}
```

(`?` appears in one control sequence name inside `breqn`.)

However, that won't work in a real document. The reason is that `breqn` works by providing 'active' definitions for a range of math-mode symbols. You *can* force past that by saving/restoring them, for example

```
\begingroup
  \catcode`\^^@=\active
  \gdef\setupnull{%
    \let\savednull^^@\let^^@\undefined
  }%
  \gdef\restorenull{\let^^@\savednull}
\endgroup
\gdef\looper#1{\ifx\relax#1\relax\else\foo#1\expandafter\looper\fi}
\gdef\fooa#1{%
  \lccode`\~=`#1 %
  \lowercase{\expandafter\let\csname saved\string#1\endcsname~}%
}
\gdef\foob#1{%
  \lccode`\~=`#1 %
  \lowercase{\expandafter\let\expandafter~\csname saved\string#1\endcsname}%
}
\gdef\chars{r<>:-!/=?}
\XMLelement{TEI.2}{}
  { \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{ifthen,url}
    \setupnull
    \let\foo\fooa
    \expandafter\looper\chars\relax
    \catcode`\?=12 % 
    \usepackage{breqn}
    \restorenull
    \let\foo\foob
    \expandafter\looper\chars\relax
    \catcode`\?=\active
    \begin{document}  }
  {\end{document}}
```

However, that is going to disable more-or-less all of how `breqn` works. I'd go with [David's conclusion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/428446/): better to use an alternative approach to generating LaTeX from XML, then having a free choice of packages.